# What is the expected number of people who don’t show up per flight?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

An airline knows that $5\%$ of the people making reservations will not show up. Consequently, their policy is to sell $52$ tickets for a flight that can only hold $50$ passengers. Define an appropriate random variable $X$ for the following question: What is the expected number of people who don’t show up per flight?

I'm not sure where to begin, but I did find that the probability of the seats available for every passenger that showed up, which is $0.741$, and the probability of seats available for every passenger that didn't show up, which is $1-0.741= 0.259$.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please provide more information other than the question itself: what steps did you take to solve the problem and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Hi, I'm actually not sure where to begin. I found the probability of seats available for every passenger that shows up which was 0.741 and the passengers that didn't show up, 0.259. I don't know what steps to take next

Answer (score 1):

Consider $X\sim\text{Binomial}(n,p)$ with $n=52$ and $p=0.05$. You are looking for $\mathbb E[X] = np$.